# How do I upload a random image from a folder to twitter in Python?

Tags: python, image, twitter, media

I'm trying to make code for a bot  that uploads an image from a specific folder every hour. I am unfamiliar with both twitter's api and Python, so I have been using online references. A friend of mine had the service they use for a bot taken down, and thought I might be able to try to figure out just enough Python to code a bot. I'm currently just trying to see if I can upload text only, I found some code on a website, but it's giving me errors in regards to api.update_status. I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix it, any help would be appreciated.

This is the code IO tried, I expected the code to upload a tweet to the account, but it gave me error messages. Here is both the code and the error messages

```
def set_up():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(Keys.api_key, Keys.api_key_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(Keys.access_token, Keys.access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    print('AAAAAAA') #test if it goes through
    return api

def run(tweet):
    api = set_up()
    api.update_status(tweet) #issue is here

run('AAAAAA')
```

Error messages:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\email\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 26, in 
run('AAAAAA')
File "C:\Users\email\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 24, in run
api.update_status(tweet)
File "C:\Users\email\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 46, in wrapper
return method(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\email\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 1142, in update_status
return self.request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\email\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 265, in request
raise Forbidden(resp)
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal.

Answer (score 0):

"*You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal*".

The answer to your problem is in your error log. You need to get the elevated API access in the developer portal. Your current essential access does not have write permission, which is needed to create media/tweets.